# Kerberos + Apache reverse proxy Windows

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, kerberos

I have verified that Kerberos works without running the Apache Proxy. The server is running Windows and the Apache reverse proxy is running on the same server. It seems I need this module for kerberos? http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/configure.html

The guides are mostly for Linux so I downgraded Apache to 2.2(I'm not sure how to compile it for Windows) and use an existing compiled version found here https://www.schaeuffelhut-berger.de/wordpress/apache-single-sign-on-in-windows/

I put the following in httpd.conf of Apache:

```
<Location />
   AuthType Kerberos
   AuthName "Kerberos Login"
   KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.SE

   Krb5Keytab C:/etc/http.keytab

   KrbMethodK5Passwd on
   KrbMethodNegotiate on

   Satisfy All
</Location>
```

There's no errors in error.log or ssl_error.log. The login pop up is appearing again after trying to login. I'm not sure if the settings in httpd.conf is correct or if the kerberos module is right.

If this is not easily done on Windows, is there an alternative to Apache HTTPD that would be easier to set up with Kerberos on Windows?

Comment: Where are you trying to login from, from on the server itself, or from another machine?  What browser are you using?  What is the output of *klist*?

Comment: The whole point of Kerberos is to authenticate a client (user) to a specific service running on a specific server (canonical DNS name), even if the network is unsecure. From this point of view, your reverse proxy acts as a man-in-the-middle attack. So why do you need a proxy, why do you need Kerberos, why do you want both?!?!?

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to login from the server itself. The browser is Internet Explorer. From how the proxy is set up it looks like it is used for SSL and so user on the intranet can connect using a domain name

Comment: Do you mean the output of klist for the keytab?